# All Redis data randomly gone

Tags: redis

Redis is a key value store that I was using as a database. Today, all the data just randomly got wiped out and there is now NOTHING in the redis instance. Is there anyway I can get this data back?

Comment: You have backup, I assume? If not, I have bad news for you.

Comment: I found the dump.rdb file andit turns out it only has limited data :/